# FORCE INDEX in MySQL - where do I put it?

Tags: mysql, indexing, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following MySQL query that works perfectly fine. Except that I need to add a `FORCE INDEX` and I'm unsure on where I have to do this. I tried just about every location and always receive a MySQL error. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the original query:

```
$sql_select_recent_items = $db->query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT owner_id, product_id, start_time, price, currency, name, closed, active, approved, deleted, creation_in_progress FROM db_products ORDER BY start_time DESC) as resultstable
WHERE resultstable.closed=0 AND resultstable.active=1 AND resultstable.approved=1 AND resultstable.deleted=0 AND resultstable.creation_in_progress=0
GROUP BY resultstable.owner_id
ORDER BY start_time DESC");
```

The query is constructed this way so that I can do the `ORDER BY` before the `GROUP BY`, in case you're wondering.

What I need to add is:

```
FORCE INDEX (products_start_time)
```

I tried it just about everywhere without success, which leads me to believe that there's something more complex that I'm missing?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The syntax for *index* hints is documented here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-hints.html

`FORCE INDEX` goes right after the table reference:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT owner_id,
           product_id,
           start_time,
           price,
           currency,
           name,
           closed,
           active,
           approved,
           deleted,
           creation_in_progress
    FROM db_products FORCE INDEX (products_start_time)
    ORDER BY start_time DESC
) as resultstable
WHERE resultstable.closed = 0
      AND resultstable.active = 1
      AND resultstable.approved = 1
      AND resultstable.deleted = 0
      AND resultstable.creation_in_progress = 0
GROUP BY resultstable.owner_id
ORDER BY start_time DESC
```

---

**WARNING:**

If you're using `ORDER BY` before `GROUP BY` to get the latest entry per `owner_id`, you're using a nonstandard and undocumented behavior of MySQL to do that.

There's no guarantee that it'll continue to work in future versions of MySQL, and the query is likely to be an error in any other RDBMS.

Search the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) tag for many explanations of better solutions for this type of query.

Answer (score 18):

`FORCE INDEX` [is going to be deprecated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html) after MySQL 8:

> Thus, you should expect `USE INDEX`, `FORCE INDEX`, and `IGNORE INDEX` to be deprecated in a future release of MySQL, and at some time thereafter to be removed altogether.

You should be using `JOIN_INDEX`, `GROUP_INDEX`, `ORDER_INDEX`, and `INDEX` instead, for v8.

From the docs you can learn that these have nuanced meanings allowing much finer-grained control over what you're telling the optimizer compared to the previous features.  You can read the full details [in the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizer-hints.html#optimizer-hints-index-level), but if all you want is the equivalent of "force index" you can do that by specifying the table and index in a special comment right after SELECT:

```
SELECT /*+ index(table_name index_name) */ col1, col2 FROM table_name;
```

Comment: if you use table alias, then you must use the alias itself in your optimizer hint, else it won't work. Ex: `player_inventories as pi` then the optimizer would be `/*+  JOIN_INDEX(pi hero_index) */`