# MySQL Index Not Working Within Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a table of vehicle information and want to search it by vin.

Create statement for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `vehicles` (
  `vehicle_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vehicle_year` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `vehicle_make` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `vehicle_model` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `vehicle_style` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `vehicle_vin` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
  `col_symbol` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `comp_symbol` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `current_value` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `unacceptable` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`vehicle_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `vehicle_unique_idx` (`vehicle_year`,`vehicle_make`,`vehicle_model`,`vehicle_style`,`vehicle_vin`,`col_symbol`,`comp_symbol`),
KEY `vehicle_vin_idx` (`vehicle_vin`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=162591 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My issue is that it seems the index isn't being used when searching by vin within the stored procedure.

Definition of the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_vehicle`(v_vin VARCHAR(17))
BEGIN

EXPLAIN SELECT
    vehicle_year,
    vehicle_make,
    vehicle_model,
    vehicle_style,
    vehicle_vin,
    col_symbol,
    comp_symbol,
    current_value,
    unacceptable,
    (1000 + (comp_symbol * .0001)) AS score
FROM
    vehicles
WHERE
    vehicle_vin = v_vin;

END
```

When I call `CALL get_vehicle('1ZVBP8EM*E');`, I get the following output:

> id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
>
> '1', 'SIMPLE', 'vehicles', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '66583', 'Using where'

So it's not using the index. However, when I run the query outside of the procedure, it uses the vin index.

The query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
    vehicle_year,
    vehicle_make,
    vehicle_model,
    vehicle_style,
    vehicle_vin,
    col_symbol,
    comp_symbol,
    current_value,
    unacceptable,
    (1000 + (comp_symbol * .0001)) AS score
FROM
    vehicles
WHERE
    vehicle_vin = '1ZVBP8EM*E';
```

returns the following:

> id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
>
> 1, SIMPLE, vehicles, ref, vehicle_vin_idx, vehicle_vin_idx, 19, const, 1, Using index condition

Why would it not use the index within the stored procedure but it does outside the stored procedure? How can I get it to use the index within the procedure?

UPDATE

So I've tried dropping the indexes and replacing them and still no luck. I've also tried creating the table with a new name and a new index name and still no luck. Each time, within the procedure, it doesn't use the index but outside of it, it does.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE #2

So I dropped the table again and created the table and a new procedure from scratch and now it works in both places. My original procedure now works too. It must have been something with the original table.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? I can not reproduce the problem. See the following SQL Fiddles: [MySQL 5.1.61](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/bde1d/1), [MySQL 5.5.32](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b7d94/1), [MySQL 5.6.6 m9](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb002/1)

Comment: I'm using 5.6.14. Those Fiddles are interesting. I've tried dropping the indexes and adding them back with no luck. Maybe I'll try it on a completely different table and see if it works.

Comment: Adda query hint `FROM vehicles USE INDEX (vehicle_vin_idx) WHERE`

Comment: What was the actual "Solution" here?  Dropping and recreating the table is a hack around some issue.  I have the same problem, but I cannot drop the table - it's full, and in a live production system.

Comment: @JasonNethercott I believe the problem stemmed from the collation being different between the system collation (which the stored procedure uses) and the table or column's collation. Or, if you're using joins, the collation being different between the two columns being joined together.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff_Lipeles.  That was the issue I finally found.  The fix for me was to cast the string passed into the procedure to match the table - then it worked fine.

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061873/force-index-mysql-where-do-i-put-it

Comment: Hi @JasonNethercott, how did you cast the parameter. Could you please provide the syntax or example.